# How to move a value from one array to the next

Tags: c++

I am making a blackjack game, and I am trying to move a card from the top of my deck to my player's hand.  I thought the code I was writing would work, however it does not send the card through. Could anyone explain why?

```
const int SHOESIZE = 208;
const int HANDSIZE = 15;    // definitely enough space
int shoeSize = 52;

void drawCard(int shoe[], int& position, int hand[], int& handSize, int &drawn)
{
handSize++;
hand[handSize-1] = shoe[position];
drawn = hand[handSize-1];
position++;
}

int humanHand[50];
int humanHandSize = 0;
int computerHand[50];
int drawn;
// initialize the deck
int shoe[SHOESIZE];
for(int i = 0; i < SHOESIZE; i++)
{
    shoe[i] = 1 + (i % 13);
}

// Shuffle the deck
int i;
int j;
int temp; // placeholder
int position;
for (i = 0; i < SHOESIZE; i++)
{
    j = 1 + rand() % 32;
    temp = shoe[i];
    shoe[i] = shoe[j];
    shoe[j] = temp;
}
position = 0; // sets position to the "top" of the deck
int hand[HANDSIZE];
// Draw Card
for(i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
{
drawCard(shoe, position, humanHand, humanHandSize, drawn);
```

Comment: Everytime you call that function, it replaces the card currently at index handsize-1. Is that what you intended?

Comment: A couple of favors to ask... 1) Could you indent your code? 2) Could you make sure it compiles stand-alone? (e.g. Is the code after `drawCard` supposed to be in `main`? Why is there an unmatched brace in the last `for` statement?)

Comment: So much raw array makes `vector` sad.

Answer (score 1):

This works I believe, I have changed the shuffling of the deck as this is more efficient and I don't think it matters that there could be different numbers of each card in the deck as long as the next card is random, but if it does then just change the code back.

I agree with atk's points, you should try to follow them (I'm aware this code below doesn't as I just directly copied the code to test and debug it).

This is pretty much the same.

```
const int SHOESIZE = 208;
const int HANDSIZE = 15;    // definitely enough space
int shoeSize = 52;

void drawCard(int shoe[], int& position, int hand[], int& handSize, int &drawn)
{
    handSize++;
    hand[handSize-1] = shoe[position];
    drawn = hand[handSize-1];
    position++;
}

int main()
{

    int humanHand[50];
    int humanHandSize = 0;
    int computerHand[50];
    int drawn;

    // initialize the deck and shuffle
    int shoe[SHOESIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SHOESIZE; i++)
    {
        shoe[i] = 1 + ( rand() % 13 );
    }

    int position = 0; // sets position to the "top" of the deck
    int hand[HANDSIZE];
    // Draw Card
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
    {
        drawCard(shoe, position, humanHand, humanHandSize, drawn);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you want to learn to count cards the value of the next card is important. Also since you can draw untill you pass 21 you could potentially draw 8 2's or something nonsensical like that.

Answer (score -1):

Lots of errors in your code... my comments as comments.  Number messed up, since i go back and forth reading code.

```
/* atk 0: where is your main() function? */
/* atk 11: what are these magic numbers?  why is 15 definitely enough space?  space for what?  why could it get as large as 15? what's it space for?  */
const int SHOESIZE = 208;
const int HANDSIZE = 15;    // definitely enough space
int shoeSize = 52;

/* atk 3: no comment explaining what the function is supposed to do, what the variables mean, and what prior and post state should be. add such a description. */
/* atk 4: no return value.  How is the caller supposed to know if there's an error?  add return value.  */
void drawCard(int shoe[], int& position, int hand[], int& handSize, int &drawn)
{
/* atk 1: fix your indentation. be consistent throughout.  I've fixed for you */
/* atk 2: you have no checks to ensure that values are as expected.  what if handsize = 0?  what if hand == null?  Add safety checks */
    handSize++;                         /* atk 5: increments the pointer, not the value.  */
    hand[handSize-1] = shoe[position];  /* atk 6: position & handsize are pointers. not values.  fix. */
    drawn = hand[handSize-1];           /* atk 7: handsize is pointer, not value  fix. */
    position++; /* atk:                 /* atk 8: using pointer instead of value. fix. */
}

/* atk 9: none of these variables have comments explaining what they are  Why whould a human have a hand of 50 cards?  Is that really 50 cards?  Or is it supposed to be fingers?  or 50 hands for 50 players?  Comment for each of these. */
int humanHand[50];
int humanHandSize = 0; /* atk 10: makes no sense. size usually means number of slots used, in which case there is a maxsize, or it means the max size.  No comment makes this ambiguous.  no maxsize makes this variable appear to mean max size. */
int computerHand[50];
int drawn;

/* atk 10: why is this stuff not in an initi() function? */
// initialize the deck
int shoe[SHOESIZE];
for(int i = 0; i &lt; SHOESIZE; i++)
{
    shoe[i] = 1 + (i % 13); /* atk 17: why the magic number 13? and why are you looking for a number between 1 and 13 ?  How do you track what suit the card is?  */
}

/* atk 12: why is this not in a shuffle() function? */
// Shuffle the deck
/* atk 13: comments missing.  what are these values for? why are you doing c-style declarations instead of inline c++ style declarations? */
int i;
int j;
int temp; // placeholder /* atk 14: no $#!%sherlock.  placeholder for what? why is it needed */
int position;
for (i = 0; i &lt; SHOESIZE; i++)
{
    j = 1 + rand() % 32; /* atk 15: why 32? there are normally 52 cards in a deck... */
    temp = shoe[i];      
    shoe[i] = shoe[j];   /* atk 16: how do you know j is less than SHOESIZE? fix. */
    shoe[j] = temp;
}
position = 0; // sets position to the "top" of the deck ?8 atk 17: thank you! a good comment! */
int hand[HANDSIZE];

/* atk 18: why is this not in a draw() function? */
// Draw Card
for(i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
{
    drawCard(shoe, position, humanHand, humanHandSize, drawn); /* atk 19: does not match function footprint.  your function takes pointers, but you are passing values */

/* atk 18: where is the rest of your code? incomplete code will not run. */
```

Comment: position and handsize are references, incrementing should be ok 5-8 are wrong

Comment: atk 19 shoe and humanHand decay automatically to pointers, the others params are by ref so value is ok

Comment: @PorkyBrain: to your first comment: right. And the pointer to the int is incremented, not the value of the int. 5-8 stand.

Comment: @PorkyBrain: I've never seen automatic decay of a value to pointer. i've seen the opposite thought, where the compiler passes the value and it's treated as a pointer. Regardless, it's generally safer to make your code explicit clear and obviously intentional,  mistake often is...otherwise what looks like a

Comment: atk if you have never seen an array decay to a pointer here is a live example http://ideone.com/8kSuqU. If you have never seen a value changed when passed by reference to a function here is an example http://ideone.com/Uvjqse. It is true that this my often be bad practice but it is not technically incorrect.